# How to pass array without the second element in c?

Tags: c

How can I pass to function my array without the second element of the array?

for example, in given array `a` , I want to pass `a[0],a[2],...,a[n-1]` to the function `f`.

Comment: you can make a copy without the 2nd element

Comment: You could create a new array and pass it, or you pass an additional variable which indicates which element is excluded. If it is every time the second element you could hande it in your code directly.

Comment: Reversed out the seemingly-obligatory -1 on the question!

Comment: Possible X-Y problem.  Why do you want to pass an array without the second element?

Comment: C does not pass arrays at all though functions.  Only an address is passed.  Providing more detail would help.

Comment: @Mathing, If you were given a comprehensive answer, can you choose it as a solution? Or write a comment if the answers didn't suit you.

Answer (score 6):

You can swap `a[0]` and `a[1]` and then pass the array from the second element: `(a + 1)`

Comment: a+1, not *(a+1) which is equivalent to a[1]

Comment: This is all very well but you can still reach the other element by pointer arithmetic.

Comment: @jaudo, Thanks!

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes but must be ensured that you can not reach the other elements with pointer arithmetic? `a[-1]` would be the initial second element, but why would a function access the `-1` index? If you copy the array,  the `a[-1]` would lead to undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: @Osiris: Dunno. It's just that you can't *forbid* a function from accessing the second element (thinking in terms of "security" here), so you may as well pass the thing in.

Comment: I like this solution.  Swap a[0] and a[1], call the function with &a[1], and then swap them back.  Simple and efficient.

Comment: I like it a lot too: it generalises readily to missing out any element.

Answer (score 2):

If you can't change the called function, and also can't change `a`:

- Allocate memory `b` for n - 1 elements
- Copy element `a[0]` in `b[0]`
- Copy from element `a[2]` to `a[n-1]` in `b[1]` to `b[n-2]` using memcpy for example.

If you can change `a`, Axifive's solution is more efficient.

Answer (score 2):

One way would be to call the function `foo` with

```
foo(a[0], a + 2)
```

assuming that `a` has at least 1 element. Personally though I'd pass the whole lot and ignore the second element in the function, particularly if `foo` is allowed to modify the first element, in which case my idea won't work. My suggestion will also wreak havoc with array indexing, and, technically you can always reach the forbidden element with pointer arithmetic.

Because of this ability to reach the element by pointer arithmetic, a way to obviate that is to copy the array *sans* element, call the function, then write back any modifications to the original array in the caller.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value of the first element and the address of the third element as two parameters, for example. But I think that passing the whole array and not using the second element in the function is the clearer solution